# How to Sign the jar file in Gradle

Tags: gradle, signing, jarsigner

I need to Sign the jar file. I did that applying plugin "signing" and add block sign like below:

```
apply plugin: 'signing' 
signing {
required { gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("makeService") }
sign configurations.archives
}
```

At the end I am able to add PGP keys and sign the jar but it is signed outside jar file with .asc (testJar.jar.asc).

But I did this in maven , it signs all class info and place the sign files in meta-inf directory.

Is there anyway to sign like that in Gradle ?

Please help I tried googling and forums not able to gain any info.

Comment: Is there really no declarative method to do this?

Answer (score 7):

```
//Signing
  // def jarsignerskip = false
  def keystoreFile = new File('urkeystore.jks')
  def keystorepass = 'keystoreP@@S'
  def keyalias = 'selfSigned'

  task signJar(dependsOn: 'jar',description: 'to Sign JAR.',group: 'Build'){

    doLast{
      println ":$project.name:${name}"
      def signdir  = new File("$buildDir/jars/signed")
      signdir.mkdirs()
      ant.signjar(
        destDir: "${signdir.absolutePath}",
                  jar: 'build/jars/*.jar',
                  alias:keyalias,
                  storetype:"jks",
                  keystore:"${keystoreFile.absolutePath}",
                  storepass:keystorepass,
                  verbose:true,
                  preservelastmodified:"true"
      )
    }

  }
```

It works for me.

Comment: If you want jars to be signed every build, add `build.dependsOn signJar` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

ASC is used for a digital signature the archive for publication.

But there you need a signed JAR

At first, do  this in console:

1) Create a private key

```
keytool -genkey -alias test_app_alias -validity 3650  -keystore test_app_sign.jks
```

As a password, use password123

2) Sign the JAR using your private key

```
jarsigner -keystore test_app_sign.jks -storepass password123 -keypass password123 build/libs/<name>.jar test_app_alias
```

3) check that everything is done correctly by looking to the resulting file. Or run the command

```
jarsigner -verify build/libs/<name>.jar
```

Add the code in build.gradle. For example:

```
jar << {
    def passwd = "password123"
    def app_alias = "test_app_alias"
    def jks_file = "test_app_sign.jks"

    def exec_line = "jarsigner -keystore " + jks_file + " -storepass " +
        passwd + " -keypass "+ passwd + " " + jar.archivePath + " " + app_alias
    print  exec_line
    exec_line.execute()
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that if signing fails, the jar file must be deleted, otherwise on the next build run, Gradle will surely think it's up to date and not sign it again.

Comment: I know it's old but... this above will just sign the jar, right? How do you generate the `.pom.asc` file using the jks? (For publishing on maven)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the error message:

```
jar {
    doLast {
        def exec_line = "jarsigner -keystore " + jks_file + " -storepass " + signer_pass + " -keypass "+ signer_pass + " " + jar.archivePath + " " + signer_alias
        print  exec_line
        exec_line.execute()
        }
}
```