# How to sign jar by jarsigner from Gradle task?

Tags: java, gradle, digital-signature, jarsigner, jar-signing

Gradle 8.6

I am trying to sign jars using jarsigner from Gradle task.

1. The first thing I did was generate a certificate:

`keytool -genkey -alias test -validity 3650 -keyalg RSA -keystore test.jks`

After entering the command, I set a password and specified all the necessary data.

2. I put the certificate in the Gradle root folder: `C:\Users\User\.gradle\test.jks`
3. I also created and filled in the global `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.warning.mode=all
testKeyStore=C:/Users/User/.gradle/test.jks
testKeyStoreAlias=test
testKeyStorePassword=test
testKeyStoreKeyPassword=test
tsa=http://time.certum.pl
```

4. Next, I created a Gradle Task:

```
tasks.register("signJars") {

    onlyIf { // Skip the task if our secret data isn't available
        project.hasProperty("testKeyStore") &&
                project.hasProperty("testKeyStoreAlias") &&
                project.hasProperty("testKeyStorePassword") &&
                project.hasProperty("testKeyStoreKeyPassword") &&
                project.hasProperty("tsa")
    }

    final def testKeyStore = findProperty("testKeyStore")
    final def testKeyStoreAlias = findProperty("testKeyStoreAlias")
    final def testKeyStorePassword = findProperty("testKeyStorePassword")
    final def testKeyStoreKeyPassword = findProperty("testKeyStoreKeyPassword")
    final def tsa = findProperty("tsa")

    for (jar in fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/libs", include: '*.jar')) {

        final List<String> args = Arrays.asList(
                "jarsigner",
                "-keystore",
                "\"${testKeyStore}\"",
                "-storepass",
                "\"${testKeyStorePassword}\"",
                "-keypass",
                "\"${testKeyStoreKeyPassword}\"",
                "-tsa",
                "\"${tsa}\"",
                "-verbose",
                "\"${jar.toPath()}\"",
                "\"${testKeyStoreAlias}\""
        ) as List<String>

        final command = args.join(" ");
        println command

        def builder = new ProcessBuilder(command)
        builder.inheritIO()
        def process = builder.start()
        def finished = process.waitFor(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        println "Finished: ${finished}"
        println "Exit value: ${process.exitValue()}"
        println "Output: ${process.text}"
    }
}
```

After Gradle Reload, I tried to run the task, to which I received an answer:

`Cannot run program "jarsigner -keystore "C:\Users\User\.gradle\test.jks" -storepass "test" -keypass "test" -tsa "http://time.certum.pl" -verbose "E:\full\path\to\project\Project\build\libs\Test.jar" "test"": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

I've tried many different variations, but I've never been able to make it work. I need help!

The most interesting thing is, if I copy the command and execute it from Windows PowerShell or IDEA, then everything works WITHOUT problems!

I was guided by the following materials when trying to implement this task:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40130109/10663941) и [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/jdavidzapatab/2afddc11c5ccaa8850060386e8a65de1)

Comment: Jarsigner.exe is part of every JDK but usually these JDK tools are not in PATH, so you have to use the full path to the executable. A common way would be to use JAVA_HOME env variable (if you have set it) which should point to the JDK dir, then you would only need zk specify the relative path to jarsigner.exe within the JDK. Alternatively you could try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/42608842.

Comment: @Robert I tried to do it like this: `System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "\\bin\\jarsigner.exe"`, but `Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\.jdks\temurin-21.0.2\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore ... `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Robert answer, I again drew attention to the ant `signjar` task, this time I managed to solve the problems that arose.
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html

```
tasks.register("signJars") {

    onlyIf { // Skip the task if our secret data isn't available
        project.hasProperty("testKeyStore") &&
                project.hasProperty("testKeyStoreAlias") &&
                project.hasProperty("testKeyStorePassword") &&
                project.hasProperty("testKeyStoreKeyPassword") &&
                project.hasProperty("tsa")
    }

    doLast {

        final def testKeyStore = findProperty("testKeyStore")
        final def testKeyStoreAlias = findProperty("testKeyStoreAlias")
        final def testKeyStorePassword = findProperty("testKeyStorePassword")
        final def testKeyStoreKeyPassword = findProperty("testKeyStoreKeyPassword")
        final def tsa = findProperty("tsa")

        ant.signjar(
                destDir: "${layout.buildDirectory.dir("libs").get()}",
                jar: "${layout.buildDirectory.dir("libs").get()}/*.jar",
                alias: testKeyStoreAlias,
                storetype: "jks",
                keystore: testKeyStore,
                storepass: testKeyStorePassword,
                keypass: testKeyStoreKeyPassword,
                tsaurl: tsa,
                verbose: true,
                force: true,
                preservelastmodified: true
        )
    }
}
```